# Javascript date and time manipulation

Tags: javascript

how to manipulate date and time in javascript on my timeline. Example, you want to write the word "good bye" on a specific date(let us say 10-20-2015) and the word, "hello world" (on 10-26-2015") how do i do it? any help is deeply appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would create a grid containing slots. Suppose each day slot within the grid has a fixed `height` of 25px. Now if you want to put some text in slot "10-20-2015", you extract the day (in this case 20th) and calculate the top offset being 20 * 25px = 500px. You append the textnode "good bye" as a `absolute` positioned element having `top:500px` relative to the grid box.

If your slots have variable dimensions, you should iterate the grid and build a map holding offset values for each slot. Something like:

```
var offsetmap=[],offsettop=0,grid=document.getElementsById('grid');
for (slot in grid.childNodes) {
  offsetmap.push(offsettop +'px');
  offsettop+=slot.offsetHeight;
}
```

In order to put a textnode in slot "10-20-2015":

```
var txtnode=document.createElement('div');
txtnode.innerHTML='good bye';
txtnode.style.top=offsetmap[20-1];
grid.appendChild(txtnode)
```